# Mavericks in Appstore twice?

Tags: macos, imac, mac-appstore

I bought my iMac a month ago and it was already set up correctly. I had to run an update on Mavericks and that was it..

After a while "OS X Mavericks" appeared on the App Store, and i can download it..

My Question is... since i HAVE Mavericks - what will the installation do ?
Will i loose my files and settings if i go further installing it or will it just run and leave everything as it is.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS X upgrades on the MAS are very different than all other products.

It is an installer as opposed to the actual program that you run.

What is available is the chance for you to re-download the installer before you need it and save a copy. Apple initially made it hard for people to re-download the installer - presumably since many are equally confused as you are. However, lots of people were confused on how to re-download the app and a change was made a while back to show it as a download to anyone that "purchased" an upgrade.

Comment: So basically i can leave it as it is... It was intended to be a safe Copy right?

Comment: Yes @TheMiniJohn - No need to do anything with it until you want to do a reinstall of the OS.

Comment: Also if you re-run the installer, it will either fail if the current OS level is higher than the installer or preserve all data and just reinstall the core OS. You only lose data during an install of there is disk corruption or a severe logic error in the scripts.